Can't get HTTPS to work with Traefik and Kubernetest Gateway API
I have the following values.yaml file that is provided when installing traefik:
providers:
  kubernetesIngress:
    enabled: false
  kubernetesGateway:
    enabled: true

deployment:
  kind: "DaemonSet"

gateway:
  enabled: true
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-production
  listeners:
    websecure:
      hostname: "*.{{domain}}"
      port: 8443
      protocol: HTTPS
      namespacePolicy: All
      certificateRefs:
        - name: whoami-tls
      mode: "Terminate"

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  annotations:
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/type: "lb11"
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: "cluster-lb"
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/network-zone: "eu-central"


Then I installed traefik like this and passed the path to the above file like this:
helm upgrade --install --version 32.1.1 --namespace traefik traefik traefik/traefik -f "values.yaml" --debug


Then after a few mins, the certificate was issued and marked as ready which I was able to verify by kubectl get certificates --all-namespaces and the output is below:
NAMESPACE   NAME         READY   SECRET       AGE
traefik     whoami-tls   True    whoami-tls   12h

Then I applied a sample route like below:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: instagram
  namespace: socials
  labels:
    app: instagram
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: traefik-gateway
      sectionName: websecure
      namespace: traefik
  hostnames:
    - "instagram-api.domain.xyz"
  rules:
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: PathPrefix
            value: "/"
      backendRefs:
        - name: instagram
          port: 80
          namespace: socials

Unfortunately, when I visited https://instagram-api.domain.xyz I get 404 page not found and also the browser tells me the connection is not secured.
If I remove the websecure from the gateway listener and switch to only web, my routes resolve perfectly fine.
This is so weird, the https websecure listener is not working.
What am I doing wrong here? I will really appreciate any help.
NB: Please note that I replaced my real domain with just domain just for this question.
